# Objective: Get from size in points to size in pixel for HTML

Tags: html, objective-c, pixel

I need to set the size of an iframe within an WKWebView to the size of my iPhone screen. I can set of course the frame of the WKWebView correctly. But my problem is, that the iframe size is completely off and too small, since points aren't the same as pixel. How can I solve that? This doesn't give me the correct screen size:

```
<iframe id='playerId' type='text/html' width='%0.0f' height='%0.0f' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/%@?enablejsapi=1&rel=0&playsinline=1&autoplay=1' frameborder='0'>\
                                </body>\
                           </html>", webView.frame.size.width, webView.frame.size.height, videoIdentifier];
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiply points to `UIScreen.mainScreen.scale`

Comment: Though your answer possibly answers the question, your answer could better by showing an actual example of how it could be done.